# Stop CPU from slowing down

Tags: cpu, cpu-load, cpufreq, scaling

When playing a 720p video file, I can hear the laptop CPU fan kick in which after a few minutes causes the video file to play back in a very choppy manner.  Is it possible to stop the CPU from slowing down like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Intel based systems, you can usually run the following as root

```
echo performance > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor
```

If you have more then one core, which is likely the case on a contemporary machine, repeat the command for each. You can find out the number of cores with

`ls /sys/devices/system/cpu/ | grep cpu[0-9]`.

To get back to the default poower level, run

```
echo ondemand > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor
```

Comment: I'm getting a permisson denied when I try that first command, even with sudo infront.

Comment: It seems to work with `CPU Frequency Scaling Monitor`, i.e. I can set it to performance, but that does not seem to make a difference.  With `CPU Frequency Scaling Monitor`, I can also set it to 30% which really slows down the video, and I can set it to 75% which makes it smooth for a short while until the CPU fans kick in and the CPU probably slows down again even though `CPU Frequency Scaling Monitor` shows it at 100%.

Comment: Run `sudo -i` to become root, and then the commands. Run `exit` when done. It would be best to put all of the commands into a script and then run it with `sudo`. If you need to run just one command with `sudo`, try this: `echo performance | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor`.

Comment: OK, with that, the command worked, but the video still becomes choppy when the CPU fans kick in.  I think I want to somehow disable to CPU slowing down feature altogether, what's that called, disabling CPU throttling/scalling?

Comment: I've see a BIOS setting on an old computer, that scaled down the CPU at a given temperature. Could that be your case?

Comment: I've tried the bios and change the appropriate to always full performance, but it makes no difference.  Thanks for the help anyway.

Answer (score 0):

sudo su

> apt-get install cpufreqd cpufrequtils gnome-applets indicator-cpufreq

and then

> indicator-cpufreq &

done